# difference between dies vs das

Tags: meaning

I have a bit of confusion between the proper use of *dies* and *das*. Both can be used as demonstrative determiner.

For example, if you are pointing out to group of people in front of you and want to show someone next to you and explain who they are. You can use both of the following, but what is the nuance between them?

1. Diese sind unsere Kandidaten
2. Das sind unsere Kandidaten

Comment: I corrected the spelling of "Kandidaten". Nouns have to be captialized, and the plural is with 'en' in the end, unless you mean a group of exclusively female candidates, then the proper plural would be "Kandidatinnen" (you description makes it sound like it could be both men and women in the group, but the please edit, if you only mean a group of women candidates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary distinction is closeness: "dies" for close things, "das" for things that are farther away. As a native, I'm not entirely sure where the boundary between "dies" and "das" lies. I recently read about a theory that most languages distinguish if things are reachable by hand, and I think that's a good criterion for German, too. When you have to point at something, that's definitely too far to use "dies".

Another criterion is if something is closer to the speaker than the addressee. If something is closer to the addressee, then "dies" is also definitely wrong.

Originally, German hat "dies" for close things and "jenes" for far things, but "jenes" has fallen out of use in spoken German, which instead uses "das". But because "das" does not imply any distance, "das" can basically used for pointing at anything. If one wants to specify distance, this is done by adding "hier"(here), "da"(there) and optionally a direction, as in "die da hinten".

In your examples, "diese" and "das" don't have the same gender. "Diese" is plural, and "das" is (singular) neuter. While pointing or showing, usually neuter is used:

> Das sind unsere Kandidaten // Dies sind unsere Kandidaten.

"Die" and "diese" would normally only be used if one was already taking about them as people.

> Wer sind die? Die sind unsere Kandidaten.

I don't know why, but I think I have been taught that referring to people with "die" is impolite, as is pointing fingers at people.

Comment: Notice that "dies" und "das" are both singular. These words address the people as *one group* (hence singular), while "diese" and "die" are plural and adress the group as a number of single persons.